# Strange performance behaviour for 64 bit modulo operation

Tags: c++, performance, 64-bit, numeric

The last three of these method calls take approx. double the time than the first four.

The only difference is that their arguments doesn't fit in integer anymore. But should this matter? The parameter is declared to be long, so it should use long for calculation anyway. Does the modulo operation use another algorithm for numbers>maxint?

I am using amd athlon64 3200+, winxp sp3 and vs2008.

```
       Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
       TestLong(sw, int.MaxValue - 3l);
       TestLong(sw, int.MaxValue - 2l);
       TestLong(sw, int.MaxValue - 1l);
       TestLong(sw, int.MaxValue);
       TestLong(sw, int.MaxValue + 1l);
       TestLong(sw, int.MaxValue + 2l);
       TestLong(sw, int.MaxValue + 3l);
       Console.ReadLine();

    static void TestLong(Stopwatch sw, long num)
    {
        long n = 0;
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (long i = 3; i < 20000000; i++)
        {
            n += num % i;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);            
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I now tried the same with C and the issue does *not* occur here, all modulo operations take the same time, in release and in debug mode with and without optimizations turned on:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "limits.h"

static void TestLong(long long num)
{
    long long n = 0;

    clock_t t = clock();
    for (long long i = 3; i < 20000000LL*100; i++)
    {
        n += num % i;
    }

    printf("%d - %lld\n", clock()-t, n);  
}

int main()
{
    printf("%i %i %i %i\n\n", sizeof (int), sizeof(long), sizeof(long long), sizeof(void*));

    TestLong(3);
    TestLong(10);
    TestLong(131);
    TestLong(INT_MAX - 1L);
    TestLong(UINT_MAX +1LL);
    TestLong(INT_MAX + 1LL);
    TestLong(LLONG_MAX-1LL);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Thanks for the great suggestions. I found that both .net and c (in debug as well as in release mode) does't not use atomically cpu instructions to calculate the remainder but they call a function that does.

In the c program I could get the name of it which is "_allrem". It also displayed full source comments for this file so I found the information that this algorithm special cases the 32bit divisors instead of dividends which was the case in the .net application.

I also found out that the performance of the c program really is only affected by the value of the divisor but not the dividend. Another test showed that the performance of the remainder function in the .net program depends on both the dividend and divisor.

BTW: Even simple additions of long long values are calculated by a consecutive add and adc instructions. So even if my processor calls itself 64bit, it really isn't :(

**EDIT3:**

I now ran the c app on a windows 7 x64 edition, compiled with visual studio 2010. The funny thing is, the performance behavior stays the same, although now (I checked the assembly source) true 64 bit instructions are used.

Comment: In regards to your last observation, if you're using regular consumer install of Windows XP, you're almost certainly running your fancy 64 bit processor in 32 bit mode.

Comment: Your processor really is 64 bit, it's your OS and compiler that are running in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried performing the same operations in native code on your box?

I wouldn't be surprised if the native 64-bit remainder operation special-cased situations where both arguments are within the 32-bit range, basically delegating that to the 32-bit operation. (Or possibly it's the JIT that does that...) It does make a fair amount of sense to optimise that case, doesn't it?

Comment: I now tried it with native code and the issue does not occur here. 
Sure it makes sense that such an optimisation is done but why is it sometimes and sometimes not.
But I don't believe it is the JIT because the value in question is passed as an argument and I don't think the method is jitted multiple times in the same process.

Answer (score 4):

What a curious observation. Here's something you can do to investigate this further:  add a "pause" at the beginning of the program, like a Console.ReadLine, but AFTER the first call to your method. Then build the program in "release" mode. Then start the program *not in the debugger*.  Then, at the pause, attach the debugger.  Debug through it and take a look at the code jitted for the method in question.  It should be pretty easy to find the loop body.

It would be interesting to know how the generated loop body differs from that in your C program.

The reason for all those hoops to jump through is because the jitter changes what code it generates when jitting a "debug" assembly *or* when jitting a program that already has a debugger attached; it jits code that is easier to understand in a debugger in those cases.  It would be more interesting to see what the jitter thinks is the "best" code generated for this case, so you have to attach the debugger late, after the jitter has run.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. I found out a lot interesting stuff, see my new edits :)