# Set Visual Studio 2010 Express to target 64 bit platforms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, .net-4.0, 64-bit

I will be upgrading to a paid edition of VS soon, but in the mean time, I'd like to solve something. I know how to edit the project file to specify specify a 32 or 64 bit target:

```
<PlatformTarget>anycpu</PlatformTarget>
```

However, I notice an extreme performance drop when executing 64 bit code, which doesn't make sense as I'm running Win 7 Home Premium 64 bit. For example, the following C# takes over 13 times longer to execute compared to the 32 bit int equivalent:

```
int T = Environment.TickCount;
long j = 0;

for (long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
{
    j = i % 1024;
}

MessageBox.Show((Environment.TickCount - T).ToString() + Environment.NewLine + 
   j.ToString());
```

I belive that the 32 and 64 bit varients should execute at the same speed on a 64 bit OS. Is there something I need to configure or install to make VS Express compile this into proper 64 bit?

I am executing the release exe.

As a note, I can't edit code in debug mode. VS reports that code cannot be editied in 64 bit mode. This is confusing, because the speed doesn't reflect the statement.

Comment: Erm, no, that can't be right.  That takes 0 nanoseconds on either target.  This code gets optimized away in the Release build since it has no side-effects.  Don't test perf in the Debug build, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I didn't test in debug mode. It was release mode, run outside of the IDE. This is also just one example of 64 bit code running slower that the 32 bit equivalent.

Comment: Ah, you're actually using C#.  I can see now after the edit, I presumed C++/CLI.  Measured with Stopwatch over 10 tries: anycpu = 440 msec, x86 = 1400 msec.  As it should be, long fits in a cpu register for x64.

Comment: Somehow that seems like a compiler bug…

Comment: @Hans what CPU do you have? I'm getting 988 ms for "int" and > 13k ms for "long" (as shown). You're getting just over 3X the time for executing 64 bit code in 32 bit, which also doesn't make sense.

Comment: i5 M560 @ 2.67 GHz.  I never tested int, the original snippet had long.  This is a moving target.  Good luck with it.

Comment: @Hans I merely mean that I get expected performance with int. I'm not moving the target.

Comment: Hehe, no, your question is a moving target.

Comment: Really? I'm asking why I'm getting expected performance with int and unexpected performance with long. Not sure what's moving ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is some thought on 32 vs. 64-bit perf on Windows here too. Might be helpful: [Strange performance behaviour for 64 bit modulo operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108744/strange-performance-behaviour-for-64-bit-modulo-operation)